# weblogic log4j Rolling appender

Tags: log4j

```
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:52)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:198)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseAppender(DOMConfigurator.java:284)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByName(DOMConfigurator.java:176)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.findAppenderByReference(DOMConfigurator.java:191)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseChildrenOfLoggerElement(DOMConfigurator.java:523)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parseCategory(DOMConfigurator.java:436)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:999)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:867)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:773)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:483)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
```

Please help me in solving this issue.
I have copied log4j.xml in the weblogic server domain but when I started server I get this exception on the console.

Comment: Can you show us the content of your XML file?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're missing `apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar` in your classpath; it is required in order to use the `RollingFileAppender`.

http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17-bin.tar.gz

Comment: It seems you are right. But also I found that I have conflict in using 2 different versions of log4j files.